# Remove multiple @ symbol from a file

Tags: text-processing, vi, json

I have a file in linux that has json data in each new line. When I open that file in `vi` editor, multiple `@` symbols show up at the end of every record in a new line. The file does have new line after every record (`$` shows up). I'm unable to remove these `@` symbol from the file. Here's a snippet of the file -

```
ABCD","REFnum":"1123"}]}
@
@
@
@
{"Act":01,"tx":
```

Can someone help and recommend a solution to remove these?

Comment: You might run a few lines through `od -t x1ac` and check. I suspect vi is substituting these for something non-displayable. Very likely to be NUL 0x00.

Comment: When I did that, I don't even see representation for @

Comment: Does your file contain very long lines? Also note that Paul_Pedant asked about NUL characters, not `@`.  Vim would show NUL characters as `@` under some circumstances.

Comment: Yes, the file has long lines. I don't see NUL as well.

Comment: so looks like I see @ in bold as the line is pretty long?

Comment: My vi does this, but it colours the @ characters (and all other controls) blue. Look at the file and `:set nu` as a vi option. Not sure of the logic, but if `vi` cannot show all of a very long line that is the last one in the current viewing area, it pads the screen with @ to indicate that it is refusing to show the first part of the next long line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste a snippet of the output of `od -t x1ac yourfile` from a few lines before `ABCD","REFnum":"1123"` up to a few lines after `{"Act":01,"tx"`

Comment: Does using `:set display+=lastline` help?  See also https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_long_lines  In short: The `@` characters are not part of your file, just an indication of long lines.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` characters do not exist in your file. It's a visual representation that the Vim editor is using when it encounters "very long lines".

You may possibly be able to navigate the file easier if first using

```
:set display+=lastline
```

but you may also reformat your JSON document to be easier to read by using the `jq` utility like so:

```
jq . myfile.json >newfile.json
```

(and then edit `newfile.json` instead).  The compact format of a JSON file could be restored with

```
jq -c . newfile.json >compact.json
```

Note that the compact and "pretty printed" variants of JSON are equivalent and a JSON parser would not care which one it was parsing.

Further information about working with long lines in Vim is found in the "Vim fandom wiki": https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Working_with_long_lines